# Как использовать с своем продукте компоненты open-source?

Tags: лицензирование

Разрабатываю софт + железо.
В софте необходимо использовать готовые решения в виде встраиваемых БД и т.д.

Какие, например движки БД типа Berkeley DB или SQlLite я могу использовать в своем софте не открывая свой исходный код?

Точнее вопрос звучит так: какие лицензии open-source позволяют использовать код сторонней библиотеки без открытия моего кода?

Answer (score 0):

Вот эти лицензии можно использовать https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_BSD

Comment: Да, еще лицензия MIT хороша. Но я думал кто-нибудь знает и может перечислить все такие лицензии. Все, которые допускают использование кода в закрытых продуктах.